# Attenuating positions and orientations in Kinect

Tags: unity-game-engine, filter, kinect, smoothing, kalman-filter

I am using Kinect to get the positions and orientations of each joint, and then I am sending them to Unity. I noticed that there are a lot of "jumps" or fluctuations in the values, for example, sometimes I don't move my hand and in Unity it rotates 180 degrees.

What I want is a **good way to smooth this fluctuations**. I heard about the Kalman filter and I implement the code written here

http://www.dyadica.co.uk/very-simple-kalman-in-c/

And it is not bad for the positions but for the orientations is not so good... If you know better approaches or a better way to implement Kalman it would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

On the prior firstly you need to check how well your sensor is able to pick up your variations and movements.
If sensor is a good one, Then Kalman filter would be a good way to start with for removing the jitters and other noise. By looking at your code, you have implemented a one dimensional KF which is fine. But in your case your requirements seems to look like you need proper orientations and positions for which you may have to design a multi-dimensional KF(equations in a matrix format to remove noise in multi-dimension). You will get a better understanding of KF by these links

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/342099/EMGU-Kalman-Filter
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/865935/Object-Tracking-Kalman-Filter-with-Ease

Try to implement multi dimension KF and see how well your system responds to it. If you are not satisfied with the performance of your system, Then you may have to extend the filter by making some changes. In the recent past there are some other variants of KF that has came into existence which are Extended KF and Unscented KF . Kalman Filter fails in some practical scenarios where

1. Noise is not Gaussian zero mean
2. Input signal from the sensor is non-linear(obvious in practical)

In practical scenarios noise is never zero mean and input is not linear. For this purpose the extension of KF has been introduced. You can go through `Extended kalman filter` and `unscented kalman filter` which overcomes the above drawbacks. Both the algorithms are improvements of KF which works on practical cases and can be understandable only if you have some idea on KF.

Comment: The EKF and UKF deal with nonlinear update and measurement functions.  Your noise is still assumed to be zero mean and Gaussian.  The typical way of dealing with nonzero mean noise is to add a bias term to your state vector (such that the filter finds the nonzero bias).  The typical way of dealing with non-Gaussian noise distribution is to ignore it and pretend it's Gaussian.

Comment: @BenJackson "The typical way of dealing with non-Gaussian noise distribution is to ignore it and pretend it's Gaussian". - I love this!